# TypeScript not type checking array constructed with Array() and populated with fill

Tags: javascript, typescript, issue-tracking, typescript2.4

TypeScript version 2.4.2, compiled with `--target ES6`

The line of code:

```
var coins: { coin: number}[] = [1,1,1]
```

causes TypeScript to throw

> error TS2322: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '{ coin: number; }[]'

However, the line:

```
var coins: { coin: number}[] = Array(3).fill(1)
```

compiles successfully, without errors.

Is this a TypeScript bug, or is it intended behavior (not type checking an array declared in this manner)?. If so, why?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think TS has implemented this [yet]

Comment: One of the challenges that TypeScript (or anything like that) faces is that it cannot assume that `.fill()` is really the stock `Array.prototype.fill` function. When the code runs, it could be anything.

Comment: @Pointy not really the issue here. Typescript assumes that the standard functions are not replaces by functions that have a different behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Array(3)` creates an array of length 3 and type `any[]` and then `fill` acts on that array. Since `any` can be assigned to any type, `any[]` can also be assigned to any other typed array (including `{ coin: number}`)

If you were to specify the type parameter for `Array` you would get an error:

```
var coins: { coin: number}[] = Array<{ coin: number}>(3).fill(1) // 1 is not assignable to { coin: number}
```

There is no way to prevent the omission of the type argument for the array unfortunately.